# How to submit form using AJAX without having to leave the page HTML Formsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, form-submit

I'm using [Formsubmit](https://formsubmit.co/) to send contact us form to my email and so far it's working.

But I would like when user send the form it does not redirect it to the source [thank you page](https://formsubmit.co/thanks.html) instead I'd like to display just thank you text on the same page. I'd like to use my own.

So I followed the [documentation](https://formsubmit.co/ajax-documentation) and I came up with the following :
Unfortunately when I try validate the form button it does not work

```
<form id="contactForm" action="https://formsubmit.co/el/myemail" method="POST">
<input type="text"   name="name">
<input type="phone"  name="phone" inputmode="tel">
<input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="Partenaires">
<input type="email"  name="email" >
<input type="text"   name="message" >
<button class="btn btn-primary border rounded-0 shadow-lg d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center" 
type="submit" name="sendData">Send</button>

<!-- <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="thanks.html">-->

<script type="text/javascript">

var frm = $('#contactForm');
var msg_res ='';

frm.submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

   
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://formsubmit.co/el/vupawa",
        dataType: 'html',
        accepts: 'application/json',
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
        $("#message").html(response);
            if(response != msg_res){
                msg_res = response; //store new response
                alert('New message received');
              }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log('An error occurred.');
            console.log(response);
        }
        complete: function(response){
         setTimeout(ajax,1000);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Note : that uncommenting this line `<input type="hidden" name="_next" value="thanks.html">` will take validate the form and go through another page which is not what I want here.

Any ideas ?

Comment: remove the action attribute from form

Comment: add the alert function in success function

Comment: Didn't work I believe the action attribute is required, also I did get alert success when I tried locally but when I tried on the host server didn't work I updated up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Prevent Submission You should return false in

```
frm.submit(function (e) { 
   return false;
})
```

Or in form tag
`<form onSubmit="return false">`

```js
var frm = $('#contactForm');
var msg_res ='';

frm.submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

   
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://formsubmit.co/el/vupawa",
        dataType: 'html',
        accepts: 'application/json',
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
        $("#message").html(response);
            if(response != msg_res){
                msg_res = response; //store new response
                alert('New message received');
              }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('An error occurred.');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false; // here a change
});
```

```html
<form id="contactForm" action="https://formsubmit.co/el/myemail" method="POST">
<input type="text"   name="name">
<input type="phone"  name="phone" inputmode="tel">
<input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="Partenaires">
<input type="email"  name="email" >
<input type="text"   name="message" >
<button class="btn btn-primary border rounded-0 shadow-lg d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center" 
type="submit" name="sendData">Send</button>

<!-- <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="thanks.html">-->
```

Comment: You don't think `e.preventDefault();` does the job already in the submit handler?

Comment: it's work for button events and we want to prevent form submissin

Comment: It definitely works for any event having a default action, it's not limited to "button events" only.

Comment: He already tried that but its not working in his case so batter try all option we have

Comment: Yes, but doing the same thing in other way won't help, returning `false` just makes jQuery to do `event.preventDefault()` internally, it won't change anything.